# Integrate Unity3D engine into WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine, rendering, collision-detection

I need to integrate a collision-detection and rendering engine into my WPF application.

As far as I understand, Unity3D comes as a standalone application with its own compiler. Is it possible to include Unity3D into my solution and use its API? Does it provide a DLL?

Comment: No, Unity3D is not an API like XNA

Comment: At most, you could embed a standalone Unity3D app inside a WPF window, or something like that. But communicating with it or using the API is not an option.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Isn't XNA about to be deprecated? I'm new to WPF programming: Is there any alternative for collision detection?